# Unix variable looks like a string but isn't

Tags: bash, unix, switch-statement

I have a variable STACK_STATUS that is assigned a value from a command, but I cant seem to identify what exactly the value is. It appears to be a string, but if you do an equality test with an equivalent string, it returns false. Specific case:

```
STACK_STATUS=$(aws cloudformation describe-stacks --query "Stacks[?StackName == '${STACK_NAME}'].StackStatus | [0]")
```

In this case `echo $STACK_STATUS` returns `"ROLLBACK_COMPLETE"`, however `[ ${STACK_STATUS} == "ROLLBACK_COMPLETE" ]; echo $?` returns `1` (It should return zero if they were the same). At first I assumed this had something to do with excessive quotations, but I tried several versions of this with different levels of quotation marks and it doesn't match.

Concequently when I try to write a command like:

```
case "$STACK_STATUS" in
    null)
        echo "stack does not exist, creating it"
        echo "do some stuff"
        ;;
    ROLLBACK_COMPLETE)
        echo "stack is in ROLLBACK_COMPLETE, deleting and rebuilding"
        echo "do some other stuff"
        ;;
    *)
        echo "updating stack with stack status: $STACK_STATUS"
        echo "do extra stuff"
        ;;
esac
```

I get this situation where it is missing the `ROLLBACK_COMPLETE` case, and echos directly `"updating stack with stack status: ROLLBACK_COMPLETE"`. This is clearly not the intended behavior.

1) How do I fix this so that the case statement correctly catches the ROLLBACK_COMPLETE case?

2) What exactly is the `$STACK_STATUS` variable if not a string?

**EDIT: Additional Info**

Running the aws command and writing a result to a file via:

```
aws cloudformation describe-stacks --query "Stacks[?StackName == '${STACK_NAME}'].StackStatus | [0]" > aws.out
```

results in a file that contains the single line:

```
"ROLLBACK_COMPLETE"
```

Comment: What shell do you use? Try single `=` as described in `man test`.

Comment: You're capturing the output of the `aws` command. Try running the same command with output to a file: `aws cloudformation ... > aws.out` and carefully examine the contents of `aws.out` (`cat -A`, `hd`, etc.) You should probably hae double quotes around the command substitution: `STACK_STATUS="$(aws cloudformation ...)"`, but if the output is a single word that wouldn't be the cause of your problem.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk: Most versions of `test` accept `==`, and those that don't should report a syntax error rather than just failing. And the failing code is using `case`, not `test`; the OP just used `[ ... ]` to verify.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I think OP means that `[ ${STACK_STATUS} == "ROLLBACK_COMPLETE" ]; echo $?` is also failing because it should return 0.

Comment: ArkadiuszDrabczyk, I'm using bash, and switching to a single = doesn't change the result. 
KeithThompson I've added additional info. I did what you said, and the file contains the string "ROLLBACK_COMPLETE" (with quotation marks). Also, wrapping the command with quotes doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Logister: what does this script https://pastebin.com/raw/7WsBQBb0 say on your machine? What version of `bash` do you have?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk, running the script results in the correct output:
STACK_STATUS == ROLLBACK_COMPLETE
0
stack is in ROLLBACK_COMPLETE, deleting and rebuilding
do some other stuff

Comment: ok, I think that Keith is correct that `"` around `ROLLBACK_COMPLETE` should be taken literally. Notice that if you changed 3rd line to `STACK_STATUS='"ROLLBACK_COMPLETE"'` you will get the behavior you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `$STACK_STATUS` is not

```
ROLLBACK_COMPLETE
```

it's

```
"ROLLBACK_COMPLETE"
```

The double quotes aren't shell syntax, they're part of the output of the command and the value of the variable.

Replace this:

```
ROLLBACK_COMPLETE)
```

by this:

```
'"ROLLBACK_COMPLETE"')
```

Here's a small script to demonstrate:

```
#!/bin/bash

STACK_STATUS='"ROLLBACK_COMPLETE"'
echo "STACK_STATUS=$STACK_STATUS"

case "$STACK_STATUS" in
    ROLLBACK_COMPLETE)        
        echo "This doesn't match"
        ;;
    "ROLLBACK_COMPLETE")
        echo "Neither does this"
        ;;
    '"ROLLBACK_COMPLETE"')
        echo "BINGO!"
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Something else?"
        ;;
esac
```

The output:

```
STACK_STATUS="ROLLBACK_COMPLETE"
BINGO!
```